# How to access a variable outside the if statement

Tags: php, if-statement

In the following code, how do i access $uname outside of this statements?

```
 $uname = '';
if ($row['ulogo'] == '1'){
    $ulogo = '../images/varsity logos/witsLogo.jpg';
    $uname = 'Wits';
    echo $uname;
    } else if ($row['ulogo'] == '2'){
        $ulogo = '../images/varsity logos/UJ.png';
    $uname = 'University of Johannessburg';
    echo $uname;
    } 
    echo $uname;
```

Explain your downvote if there's one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Initialize $uname outside the if block:

```
$uname = '';
if ($row['ulogo'] == '1'){
    $ulogo = '../images/varsity logos/witsLogo.jpg';
    $uname = 'Wits';
    echo $uname;
    } else if ($row['ulogo'] == '2'){
        $ulogo = '../images/varsity logos/UJ.png';
    $uname = 'University of Johannessburg';
    echo $uname;
} 
echo $uname;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a PHP guy so correct me if I'm wrong... but to access $uname, outside of the if statement you have to declare it outside the if statement, so it is in scope outside the if statement. Right now $uname is only in scope within the if statement, once you leave the if statement the variable no longer exists.

Comment: PHP has no block scope for variables, so they are available until the end of the function once they have been assigned a value.

Answer (score 0):

You will get notice undefined variables `$ulogo` and `$uname` if `$row['ulogo']` is not `1` or `2`.

Try this :

```
if ($row['ulogo'] == '1')
{
    $ulogo = '../images/varsity logos/witsLogo.jpg';
    $uname = 'Wits';
}
elseif ($row['ulogo'] == '2')
{
    $ulogo = '../images/varsity logos/UJ.png';
    $uname = 'University of Johannessburg';
} 
else
{
    $ulogo = '../images/varsity logos/noimage.png';
    $uname = NULL;
}

echo $ulogo;
echo $uname;
```

Or

```
$logo   = '../images/varsity logos/noimage.png';
$uname  = NULL;

if ($row['ulogo'] == '1')
{
    $ulogo = '../images/varsity logos/witsLogo.jpg';
    $uname = 'Wits';
}
elseif ($row['ulogo'] == '2')
{
    $ulogo = '../images/varsity logos/UJ.png';
    $uname = 'University of Johannessburg';
} 

echo $ulogo;
echo $uname;
```

Answer (score -1):

> First You Define Global Variable
>
> $uname = '';
>   if ($row['ulogo'] == '1'){
>
> $ulogo = '../images/varsity logos/witsLogo.jpg';
>
> $uname = 'Wits';
>
> echo $uname;
>
> } 
>   else if ($row['ulogo'] == '2'){
>
> ```
>    $ulogo = '../images/varsity logos/UJ.png';
> ```
>
> $uname = 'University of Johannessburg';
>
> echo $uname;
>   }
>
> echo $uname;

Answer (score -1):

Your Code is Working. I have give example it's match

```
$row = 1; //temp variable

if ($row == '1'){
    $uname = 'Wits';
} else if ($row == '2'){
    $uname = 'University of Johannessburg';
} 

echo $uname;
```

Answer (score -1):

The above answer is correct, I just thought I'd add another way-

Define your if statement inside a function that returns eg

```
function define_username() {
    if ($row['ulogo'] == '1'){
       $ulogo = '../images/varsity logos/witsLogo.jpg';
       $uname = 'Wits';
    } else if ($row['ulogo'] == '2'){
       $ulogo = '../images/varsity logos/UJ.png';
       $uname = 'University of Johannessburg';
    };
    return $uname;
};

echo define_username();
```

Comment: Why do you ask? Stack Overflow is for writing [correct] answers, not for testing your skills.

Comment: I wasn't 'testing my skills', I was providing another way to do the same thing.  When you're starting out it can help to see different ways of doing things.  Also, this way he can access the variable inside other functions

Comment: unfortunately, this approach suffers from many (quite basic) issues. $row['ulogo'] won't be available inside, as well as $ulogo outside. And, worse of all - it doesn't solve the very problem stated.